# Creating generic lambdas in Java

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

In java, you can add Type parameters to static methods, to create methods that handle generics.  Can you do the same with lambdas?

In my code I have

```
final private static <K,V> Supplier<Map<K, List<V>> supplier=HashMap::new;
```

I'm trying to do type parameters like it's a function, but it won't let me.

And if I do:

```
    final private static Supplier<Map<?, List<?>>> supplier=HashMap::new;
```

It doesn't accept the argument where I try to use it.  What can I do?

Comment: That cannot be a variable. In fact, it's useless to declare a variable like `WhateverClassThatSupportsGenerics<?> var = ...;` unless it's a parameter of a method.

Comment: Where do you try to use the second declaration?  (The first, as you've likely discovered, is syntatically invalid.)

Comment: It is not possible to construct a bounded generic object.  Your line of code fails for the same reason `new HashMap<Integer, List<?>>` is legal, but `new HashMap<?, List<?>>` is not.  `?` means "I don't know what type this HashMap uses," but when you create a HashMap, you always know what you intend to put in it (even if you decide it's java.lang.Object).

Comment: @VGR: thanks to the “diamond operator”, that rule is obsolete. You *can* say `HashMap<?, ?> map=new HashMap<>();` without specifying actual type arguments. Though such a map would not be of much use…

Comment: @Holger Interesting.  I didn't know that was possible.  I've always assumed the diamond operator was just a convenience that saved a bit of typing.

Comment: @VGR: It *is* just a convenience. But without it, even if you assign the result to a type with wildcards immediately, you have to fill in non-wildcard types. But whether you say `HashMap<?, ?> map=new HashMap<?,?>();` (which isn’t allowed) or `HashMap<?, ?> map=new HashMap<Object,Object>();` makes no real difference. With the diamond operator, you don’t need to think about whether it infers `?` or `Object`. The result is as if you can instantiate everything which you can declare as target type, including wildcarded types…

Answer (score 8):

One workaround for this may be to wrap the method reference into a method, so that target type deduction resolves the type at the call site:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class GenericLambda
{
    // Syntactically invalid
    //final private static <K,V> Supplier<Map<K, List<V>> supplier=HashMap::new;

    final private static Supplier<Map<?, List<?>>> supplier=HashMap::new;

    // A workaround
    private static <K,V> Supplier<Map<K, List<V>>> supplier()
    {
        return HashMap::new;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Does not work
        //useSupplier(supplier);

        // Works
        useSupplier(supplier());
    }

    private static <K, V> void useSupplier(Supplier<Map<K, List<V>>> s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a cast on `HashMap::new` which is `Map<Object,Object>` (or `Map<?,?>`) but not `Map<?,List<?>>`). See how `Collections.emptyList()` is implemented.

Comment: @NoDataFound Not sure what you mean, but here, no cast is required (although a brutal cast might be safe as well in this case, as all type parameters turn into `Object` anyhow when they are compiled...)

Comment: @NoDataFound: The list returned by `Collections.emptyList()` is immutable and therefore it is possible to always return the same object and just cast it. In this case, however, you always get a new `HashMap` and using `HashMap::new` the compiler can infer the correct generic parameters automatically. Nevertheless it would be possible to always cast and return the static field. But casting in this case is a bit inconvenient: You need to use `(Supplier<Map<K, List<V>>>) (Supplier<?>) supplier`. And it produces warnings about unchecked casts and performance should usually make no difference.

Comment: Though there is not much benefit in writing `supplier()` as a method argument instead of directly writing `HashMap::new` at that place…

Comment: @Holger It depends. When such a supplier is supposed to be used at multiple places, one can later easily change the *single* occurance of `HashMap::new` into `LinkedHashMap::new`, instead of having to replace it everywhere where it is used. (Of course, one could also introduce a single `supplierSupplier` field here, but I guess that's not the point...)

Comment: That would imply that all call sites similarly agree that such a switch of the implementation class is acceptable and even intended. Otherwise, you have to go through all place and verify this assumption. And while the possibility of changing `HashMap::new` to `LinkedHashMap::new` at a single method sounds like a huge advantage from a pure OO view, it isn’t in a world where we have decent search-and-replace tools which can not only replace all occurrences of `HashMap::new` to `LinkedHashMap::new` but also show each place to allow the programmer’s intervention…

Comment: @Holger: I'm not sure what you are questioning here: All this is known as the *factory method* pattern. And according to Lishkov, everything that works with a `HashMap` also works with a `LinkedHashMap`. However, I just wanted to sketch a workaround to achieve the goal that the OP described.

Comment: There must be a reason why not everyone is using `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` all the time… Nevertheless, you just wanted to sketch a workaround to achieve the goal that the OP described, assuming that this is what the OP wanted, as I can’t really deduce from the question why he tries what he tries, and I only wanted to mention that I don’t see a real benefit of wrapping an expression as simple as `HashMap::new` in a factory method (especially a `private` one). Not without a specified purpose for the factory method. But maybe the OP will come back and tell us a bit more about it…

Comment: So everyone has told what he wanted to tell and everything is fine…

Comment: I think the HashMap:new is just a simple use case to demonstrate in a question. The reason I am here reading is because I want to use a strategy pattern where an enum has a reference to a given function. I was trying to define the type for my `private final Function<I, O> strategy;` field and found  out that It isn't supported in the syntax.